# Epson TM20|| printer arabic printing glyphs shaping

Tags: java, android, printing, epson

I am trying to print arabic characters from epson printer. All is working fine just that arabic print is not containing shape . Letters are not joined.
Example: قيمت واحد  is being printed as ق ي م ت و ا ح د. 
I am using java and usb host class for printing. Sending bytes to bulk transfer.

```
byte[] ARABIC_TO_PRINT = {(byte) 0xCF, 0x01, (byte) 0xCD, 0x03, (byte) 0xC7, 0x00, (byte) 0xE6, 0x00, (byte) 0x20, (byte) 0x0CA, 0x01, (byte) 0xE3, 0x02, (byte) 0xED, 0x02, (byte) 0xDE, 0x03};

   print(mConnection,mInterface,ARABIC_TO_PRINT);
```

My print function is working fine and printing any bytes i am giving to it.

```
 private void print(UsbDeviceConnection connection, UsbInterface intrface, byte[] array) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

      if (intrface == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "INTERFACE IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (connection == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "CONNECTION IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (forceCLaim == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "FORCE CLAIM IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        assert connection != null;
        connection.claimInterface(intrface, forceCLaim);
        connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, array, array.length, 0);

    }
```

Please suggest anything for arabic shaping.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Printed my receipt as image.And it worked like charm.

Comment: i am also facing same issue for Arabic receipt printing(58mm/80mm) in android java. can you please share the code for converting the Arabic receipt to image and printing via Bluetooth or explain how to do it in android java